# How to check if the user has logged in so you can redirect to login page if the user is not logged in onsubmit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, submit

Here I want to check if the user has logged in when submit button is clicked. If the user has logged in display "submitted" and if not redirect to login page.
I have a submit button that I want to use as a check when clicked. How do I check if the user has logged in, in the controller?

```
(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
          return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
          }
```

I also want to know how to control the submit button that is in the view here--in the controller--so that when it is clicked I can check if the user has logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

The check on User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will tell you if the user is logged in and can be used in te controller code or in a view in razor code.

You could just decorate the post method of the controller with the [Authorize] attribute and when you are not logged in then you will automatically do the redirected to login controller for you, assuming that the web config file is set up to handle forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" >
</authentication>
```

Having automatically dealt with the redirect when not authorized you can just deal with the logged in code case inside your controller code.